# Displaying workgroup details on powerline or telephone-line modeline

Tags: powerline, workgroups

I recently came across various workgroup extensions for Emacs and have been doing some experiments. I had a look at:

1. [eyebrowse](https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse)
2. [workgroups](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el)
3. [workgroups2](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2)

(I have currently settled with workgroups2)

I could see the workgroup details on the default Emacs modeline but as soon as I enable the [powerline](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline) or the [telephone-line](https://github.com/dbordak/telephone-line), I could not see the workgroups anymore, except for the **wg** as an indication that the minor-mode is enabled.

Can anyone provide me a few pointers for how I can get it on the custom mode-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *intense* research on Emacs modeline and **workgroups2** code, I finally figured it out!

Turns out that the expression `wg-mode-line-string` can be used to construct a segment for telephone-line like

```
(telephone-line-defsegment telephone-line-workgroups2-segment
  (wg-mode-line-string))
```

It is now integrated in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/myTerminal/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/myTerminal/packages.el).

Comment: And, it has also been added into the official [telephone-line](https://github.com/dbordak/telephone-line) package :)